automatic translation using laravel and php
I'm relatively new to Laravel, and my manager has tasked me with automatically translating our website from English to Arabic and vice versa, while ensuring that the localization of content is respected for each language. I've been searching for solutions for the past two weeks, but I haven't been able to find a satisfactory method.
I'd prefer not to use the lang folder to manage translations because it's not practical, especially considering that the person managing the website is not a developer and shouldn't have to edit code each time a translation is needed.
I've heard about ChatGPT and its potential to assist with automatic translation, but I'm unsure about the process. Can anyone provide guidance or suggest alternative solutions to achieve automatic translation and localization in Laravel?
Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You probably need a translation API

why does it need to be automatic? the end user using the site can already use any automatic tool of choice to translate your site. Why can't the admin provide both translations when creating a post for example?

Why not use google translate plugin ?
Here is a quick copy paste example of one I used in my projects:
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function googleTranslateElementInit() {
            new google.translate.TranslateElement({
                    pageLanguage: 'bg',
                    includedLanguages: 'en,el,ro,sr,mk,bg',
                    autoDisplay: false,
                    gaTrack: true,
                    gaId: '{replace with your gaId}'
                },
                'google_translate_element')
        }
    </script>

Here is a screenshot of how the end result looks on my site: https://prnt.sc/Zt38hoWaqb_S
Edit: You also need an empty google_translate_element div:
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>


As the person managing is not developer, you could consider creating a lang table, the idea is to reproduce the behavior of "the lang folder" but this time in database. In Laravel part, you create methods that will make it easier for you to directly retrieve these translations to display them according to your localization conditions. This way, it will allow the manager to manage translations if necessary in a user-friendly administration interface (of course, if it exists)

thank you i will let my website in arabic in the first time then i will use one of those answers , thanks for ur time
